# How to display foreign key data

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table (leave, employee, department)

Here is my database

employee table:
{ Emp_ID (PK), Emp_Fname, Emp_Lname, ContactNo_HP, ContactNo_Home, Emp_Email, Dept_ID(FK)}

leave table:
{ Leave_ID (PK), Date_Apple, Leave_Type, Leave_Start, Leave_End, Status, Emp_ID(FK)}

department table:
{ Dept_ID (PK), Dept_Name, Dept_Desp}

When i click "Detail" it will come out a new page. Only specific

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["Leave_ID"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Emp_ID"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Date_Apply"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Leave_Type"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Leave_Start"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Leave_End"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Status"];?></td>
    <td><a href="app_status.php?id=<?php echo $row[Leave_ID];?>"
           target="_blank">Detail</a></td>
</tr>
```

In the new page I having a problem to display (Emp_Name, Dept_Name, ContactNo_HP, ContactNo_Home) as Emp_ID is foreign key in leave table and Dept_Name is in department table which link Dept_ID as a foreign key in employee table.

I use following statement in the new page to display data

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("select * from `leave`");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to retrieve Leave_ID in the details page:

```
$leaveID = $_GET['Leave_ID'];
```

Then you have to write a SQL code that select from the three tables and assign it to a variable (like $sql):

```
select t1.Emp_Name, t2.Dept_Name, t1.ContactNo_HP, t1.ContactNo_Home
  from employee as t1 inner join department as t2
       on t1.Dept_ID = t2.Dept_ID inner join `leave` as t3
       on t3.Emp_ID = t1.Emp_ID
 where t3.Leave_ID = ?
```

At this point I suggest you to use a MySQLi object with a prepared statement:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $leaveID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($empName, $deptName, $contactNoHP, $contactNoHome);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    \\your code to display details here
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Please note that:

1. "leave" is a reserved word, so you have to enclose it between back quotes in your SQL statement;
2. You have the Emp_ID in your page, so you should pass it instead of Leave_ID; this will help you writing a cleaner SQL statement.

Comment: May i knw why in the $stmt ->bind_result(...); four of the variable need to pass in

Comment: Method `bind_result` binds columns in the result set to variables. Your query contains 4 fields so you have to pass 4 variables that will store one field each. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)