# display multiple data from multiple different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 different table in my database which are:

```
Leave {leave_id, leave_type, emp_id}
Employee {emp_id. emp_name, dept_id}
Department {dept_id, dept_name}
```

I wish to select leave_type, emp_name and dept_name based on leave_id.

How should I write this query?

Thanks

Comment: Google `MySQL Join`. Also: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html AND http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Is it the same exercise as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441735/how-to-display-foreign-key-data/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select l.leave_type, e.emp_name, d.dept_name 
    FROM Leave l 
        JOIN Employee e ON l.emp_id = e.emp_id 
        JOIN Department d ON e.dept_id = l.dept_id 
    WHERE l.leave_id = '1'; //give leave_id which you want
```

Use the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select leave_type, emp_name ,dept_name from Leave, Employee, Department where Leave.emp_id = Employee.emp_id AND Employee.dept_id = Department.dept_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT leave_type, emp_name, dept_name 
FROM   Leave as l
JOIN   Employee as e ON e.emp_id = l.leave_id
JOIN   Department as d ON d.dept_id= l.leave_id
WHERE  leave_id = $id
```

Answer (score 0):

This option will return all rows where the join condition is met.

```
SELECT leave_type, emp_name, dept_name
FROM Leave
INNER JOIN Employee ON Leave.emp_id = Employee.emp_id
INNER JOIN Department ON Employee.dept_id = Department.dept_id
WHERE Leave.leave_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

USE **LEFT JOIN** to Force join even when one of them has no value.

```
SELECT leave.leave_type, emp.emp_name, dept.dept_name
    FROM Employee emp
     LEFT JOIN Leave leave on emp.emp_id = leave.emp_id
     LEFT JOIN Department dept on dept.dept_id = emp.dept_id
 WHERE
 leave.leave_id='{$YOUR_VALUE}'
```